# Ruby can't load 'random', a default gem

Tags: ruby, rubygems, archlinux

It's my first time using Ruby and I'm working with `random`. When I run `ruby main.rb` I get this error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    6: from main.rb:3:in `<main>'
    5: from main.rb:3:in `require_relative'
    4: from /home/groctel/Documents/Repositories/civitas-ruby/Civitas/lib/civitas_juego.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
    3: from /home/groctel/Documents/Repositories/civitas-ruby/Civitas/lib/civitas_juego.rb:4:in `require_relative'
    2: from /home/groctel/Documents/Repositories/civitas-ruby/Civitas/lib/dado.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
    1: from /usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require': cannot load such file -- random (LoadError)
```

So, I diligently checked the files. Here is the trace:

**main.rb**

```rb
# encoding:utf-8

require_relative "civitas_juego.rb"
require_relative "dado.rb"
require_relative "practica3.rb"
require_relative "vista_textual.rb"

# ...
```

**dado.rb**

```rb
# encoding:utf-8

require 'random'
require 'singleton'
require_relative 'diario'

# ...
```

And the deepest source of the error, **kernel_require.rb**

```rb
  def require(path)
    RUBYGEMS_ACTIVATION_MONITOR.enter

    path = path.to_path if path.respond_to? :to_path

    if spec = Gem.find_unresolved_default_spec(path)
      Gem.remove_unresolved_default_spec(spec)
      begin
        Kernel.send(:gem, spec.name)
      rescue Exception
        RUBYGEMS_ACTIVATION_MONITOR.exit
        raise
      end
    end

    # If there are no unresolved deps, then we can use just try
    # normal require handle loading a gem from the rescue below.

    if Gem::Specification.unresolved_deps.empty?
      RUBYGEMS_ACTIVATION_MONITOR.exit
      return gem_original_require(path) # <- THIS IS LINE 54
    end
```

I am running Arch Linux with ruby 2.6.5-1. As I understand [from the documentation](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Random.html), `random` is a kernel class and not a gem I have to build myself. Despite this, I've tried `gem install random` and gotten this error:

```
Building native extensions. This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing random:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: /home/groctel/.gem/ruby/2.6.0/gems/random-0.2.1/ext/random
/usr/bin/ruby -I /usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0 -r ./siteconf20191112-16451-127m0rj.rb extconf.rb
creating Makefile

current directory: /home/groctel/.gem/ruby/2.6.0/gems/random-0.2.1/ext/random
make "DESTDIR=" clean

current directory: /home/groctel/.gem/ruby/2.6.0/gems/random-0.2.1/ext/random
make "DESTDIR="
compiling mersenne_twister_ext.c
mersenne_twister_ext.c: In function ‘mt_initialize’:
mersenne_twister_ext.c:294:25: error: ‘struct RArray’ has no member named ‘len’
  294 |     if (RARRAY(arg_seed)->len < N)
      |                         ^~
mersenne_twister_ext.c:295:29: error: ‘struct RArray’ has no member named ‘len’
  295 |       max = RARRAY(arg_seed)->len;
      |                             ^~
mersenne_twister_ext.c: At top level:
mersenne_twister_ext.c:246:17: warning: ‘differ’ is static but declared in inline function ‘hash’ which is not static
  246 |   static uint32 differ = 0;  // guarantee time-based seeds will change
      |                 ^~~~~~
make: *** [Makefile:245: mersenne_twister_ext.o] Error 1

make failed, exit code 2

Gem files will remain installed in /home/groctel/.gem/ruby/2.6.0/gems/random-0.2.1 for inspection.
Results logged to /home/groctel/.gem/ruby/2.6.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.6.0/random-0.2.1/gem_make.out
```

I don't know how to proceed after this and looks like I'm going the wrong direction.
What do I have to do to make `random` load?

Comment: It looks like you're making it harder than it really is. Did you test your guess in IRB to see what it'd reveal? That's always a good first step.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to require `random` because it's already included in Ruby. So there's no gem to install, nothing to require, you can basically just use it.

Comment: Is it possible that it may have been needed in earlier versions?

Comment: Maybe, you can check to see if it's in Ruby core. But you have Ruby 2.6, which is one of the newest I think.

Comment: It doesn't rise any more errors after deleting the requirement, so I guess I'm good. This is a university assignment and it's very probable they're using an ancient version :/

Comment: @Groctel you may be thinking of [SecureRandom](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.5.1/libdoc/securerandom/rdoc/SecureRandom.html), which does need to be required. Kernel.rand does not.

Comment: Ahh, I see that makes a lot of sense. If the University version told you to require 'random', then maybe in the past it wasn't in Ruby. Yeah, what Chris Heald said. I think I've used SecureRandom way more than random, and it's something you have to require.

Comment: @Groctel "Is it possible it may have been needed in earlier versions?" No, don't think so. [`rand`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-1.8.6/Kernel.html#method-i-rand) is found in the Core in Ruby 1.8.6 which was from years ago, and I've been using Ruby since before then and don't remember having done anything special to access it.

Comment: [I'm going to have to agree with @theTinMan](https://github.com/search?l=Ruby&q=%22require+random%22&type=Code).